# Adding a button to last page of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in my application and i want to basically add a button on the final page. Right now i add the button in story board under the **Scroll View** and set the X parameter of the button to 1050 which is (screenWidth*3 + 90) with screenWidth as 320 (iPhone5). So as you can see it works on iPhone5 but doesn't work on larger screens 6/6Plus. I tried to readjust the button programatically but it didn't work.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ...


    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page1];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page2];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page3];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page4];

    [self.tutorialScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth*4, screenHeight)];

    //readjust button

    CGRect btFrame = self.tutorialFinish.frame; //self.tutorialFinish is a UIButton
    btFrame.origin.x = (90 + screenWidth * 3);
    btFrame.origin.y = 492/568 * screenHeight;
    self.tutorialFinish.frame = btFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust `center` of the btn:

```
self.tutorialFinish.center =  CGPointMake(90 + screenWidth * 3 + self.tutorialFinish.frame.size.width/2, 
                                          492/568 * screenHeight + self.tutorialFinish.frame.size.height/2);;
```

Comment: yeah the button is appearing on the third page..same as what it was before

Comment: Did you connect `tutorialFinish` with the button on the storyboard?

Comment: @stud91 Do you use any constraints?

Comment: yes its connected. my constraints are leading space of 1050 to superview

Comment: "constraints are leading space of 1050 to superview". That's why you can't change position of the btn.

Comment: @stud91 remove constraints -> clean project -> build again.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `UIScrollView` with some other `UIView` to know the screen size. You can later pass it in automatic way to your scroll view as lets say `layoutView`. In code I mean, I don't know how to do such a thing in Storyboards but I assume it is possible.

From then you should be able to adjust your views to any existing or future screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(screenwidth * (page-1)+ (screenwidth
-self.button.frame.size.width)/2, y position, button width, button height);
```